# How do you edit the default `__author__ = name` line in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In pycharm, when making a new "Python File" it has some content by default: 
`__author__ = 'david'`.

What I want to do, is changing this default content by the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This way, when opening new python files on pycharm, this content above will already be there. How to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In PyCharm, go to  **Preferences** > **IDE Settings** >  **File and Code Templates** and then click on the Python Script template and change it from the default to whatever you want.

Thanks for the question, I always thought the `__author__ = blah` was annoying but never took the time to learn how to fix it.

Comment: The menu path is now **File > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates**

Answer (score 5):

The menu path is now **File > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates**. You might need to change it on multiple templates depending upon how many of your Python templates have this at the top.