# Add import statements to the beginning of new file

Tags: python, pycharm

Every time I create new Python file it starts with `__author__ = 'username'`. I don't want have this, but I want to have import of some modules, for example, `from __future__ import division`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Go to `File -> Settings -> File and Code Templates -> Python Script` and then change it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm, go to Preferences > IDE Settings > File and Code Templates > Python Script

and add whatever you want there.

Now every time you create new `.py` file it will be there

See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786317/how-do-you-edit-the-default-author-name-line-in-pycharm).